# Entity Framework Code First CTP4 Default Column Values?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity, ctp4

I have been looking into Code First with Entity Framework CTP4 and you can use the ModelBuilder to build up your table columns. Is there a way to set the default value for a column in the database using the ModelBuilder or some other mechanism?

Thank You!

Comment: [Relevant suggestion](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2929682-support-database-default-values-in-code-first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to add default value other than manualy edit via text editor / application
This is a bug in the Entity Framework...

Comment: It there a way to set the default value but it doesn't work, a bug? Or is it just missing that feature altogether in the current version?

Comment: A missing feature should not be qualified as a bug.

Answer (score 38):

I am using the constructor to set the default values. Never failed me

```
public class Activity
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }

    public Activity()
    {
        AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is not getting enough love.

Comment: Only problem is DB default values are more efficient.

Comment: ofcourse, but until it's released in the next release of EF, that will do the trick

Comment: Except that it doesn't actually answer the question, it does provides a work-round but that's not what was asked for and therefore the *right* answer (to the question, as asked) is that its not supported and hence the other is accepted.

Comment: Because there is no other way to solve it but this way. It's got 17 points, oh wait, it doesnt solve the bug in Entity Framework (which is out of the scope), so it can't be accepted. Bummer.

Comment: Erm, I'll repeat, you're NOT solving the problem and not answering the question - its a work-round and, yes, a valid approach and definitely useful (which is what the upvotes acknowledge) but that still doesn't make it the "right" answer. The upvotes will allow other users to make an assessment of whether it solves the problem for them (although it does't for my use case).

Comment: Ok, should remove the solution, I mean, the "work around" until it is solved by the real solvers, Microsoft?

Comment: @Murph aparently 21 people believe this is the correct answer. I am thinking of opening a new question, posting my answer there and removing this answer from here.

Comment: @Korayem no, they don't - they think that the answer is useful (which it is) but "useful" does not necessarily mean the same thing as "right" in the context of answering a question. Is this being pedantic? Of course it is (-:

Comment: And none of this works when you are migrating a column from "allow nulls" to "not allow nulls", in which case you need to have a default constraint on the column in your database.

Comment: This works perfectly with EF6 and a completely blank (starting from scratch) database.

Answer (score 4):

In the code generated for a migration, you can specify a default value for a column:

```
AddColumn("users", "ReceiveSummaryEmail", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my way, setting important properties with `private setters` in a creation method instead via the constructor

**Model**

```
public class User
{
    public static User Create(Action<User> init)
    {
        var user = new User();
        user.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        user.Since = DateTime.Now;
        init(user);
        return user;
    }

    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50), Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress, Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255), Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [StringLength(16), Required]
    public string Salt { get; set; }

    public DateTime Since { get; private set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; private set; }
}
```

**Creation of new user**

```
context.Users.Add(User.Create(c=>
{
    c.Name = "User";
    c.Email = "some@one.com";
    c.Salt = salt;
    c.Password = "mypass";
    c.Roles = new List<Role> { adminRole, userRole };
}));
```