# EF 6 Codefirst -Setting default value for a property defined in base class using fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have a base class which has audit properties like

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    [Column(Order = 1)] 
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public long ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

All my poco classes derive from this class.

I am trying to set a default value to the IsActive properties. I am not keen on using annotations and hence was wandering if I can work this using fluent API.

I tried this but it does not work. Seems like it creates a new table named BaseModel

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseModel>()
    .Property(p => p.IsActive)
    .HasColumnAnnotation("DefaultValue", true);
```

Can any one suggest a way here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554050/entity-framework-6-code-first-default-value

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do this. It can't set default values with Entity Framework. Instead you can use the constructor

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    protected BaseModel()
    {
        IsActive = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this problem by **overriding** the **SaveChanges** method. See below for my solution.

1. **Solution Explain**

   i) Override the SaveChanges method in the DbContext class.

   ```
   public override int SaveChanges()
   {
       return base.SaveChanges();
   }
   ```

   ii) Write logic to set default values

   ```
   public override int SaveChanges()
   {
       //set default value for your property
       foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("YOUR_PROPERTY") != null))
       {
           if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
           {
               if (entry.Property("YOUR_PROPERTY").CurrentValue == null)
                   entry.Property("YOUR_PROPERTY").CurrentValue = YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE;
           }
       }

       return base.SaveChanges();
   }
   ```
2. **Example**

   i) Create Base Class

   ```
     public abstract class BaseModel
     {
          [Column(Order = 1)] 
          public long Id { get; set; }
          public long CreatedBy { get; set; }
          public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
          public long ModifiedBy { get; set; }
          public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
          public bool IsActive { get; set; }
     }
   ```

   ii) override **SaveChanges**

   ```
   public override int SaveChanges()
   {

       //set default value for IsActive property
       foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("IsActive") != null))
       {
           if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
           {
               if(entry.Property("IsActive").CurrentValue == null)
                   entry.Property("IsActive").CurrentValue = false;
           }
       }

       return base.SaveChanges();
   }
   ```