# Why isn't DefaultValue affecting the migration code?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, default-value

*NB. This is not a question on how to get in the default value using other approaches. I'm just curious why the attribute doesn't seem to influence the up-migration code.*

I've altered my class by adding the attribute for default value like this. But the addition doesn't seem to come through in the up code.

```
public class Thing
{
  [Key] public Guid Id { get; set; }
  [DefaultValue("Boom")] public string Info { get; set; }
}

public override void Up()
{
  AddColumn("dbo.Things", "Info", c => c.String());
}
```

I was expecting something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27920032/1525840) presents.

```
public override void Up()
{
  AddColumn("dbo.Things", "Info", c => c.String(defaultValue: "Boom"));
}
```

Isn't the attribute in effect? Deprecated? Not for Code First migrations?