# How to set a default value on a Boolean in a Code First model?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an existing table / model into which I want to drop a new Boolean column. This table already has many hundreds of rows of data, and I can't touch the existing data. But.. This column will NOT be nullable, so I need to provide a default value of `true` to all the rows that currently exist.

```
public class Revision
{
    ...
    public Boolean IsReleased { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

**IMPORTANT:**

(This was in the OP, but people seemed to miss is.)

When databases are updated with the migration, all existing rows which receive this new column MUST have their values set to True.

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27920032/1166719

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Another option is create a default constructor and set the properties with the default values you need:

```
public class Revision
{
    public Boolean IsReleased { get; set; }

    public Revision()
    {
        IsReleased=true;

    }
}
```

To set the values to `true` of the existing rows when you run `Update-Database` command, you could do this in your `Configuration` class:

```
protected override void Seed(YourContext context)
{
    var entities=context.Revisions.Where(r=>!r.IsReleased)
    foreach(var e in entities)
    {
      e.IsReleased=true;
     //context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified; If you have disabled change tracking then add this line
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

### Update

If it is a new column you are adding via migration maybe you can also do this:

```
AddColumn("dbo.Revisions", "IsReleased", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true));
```

Comment: Ok, but I don't think this will set existing rows in existing DB's to true when the column is added, will it?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston, check what I have added to my solution

Comment: Not sure why it got downvoted. I voted it back  up.  I appreciate the update.

Comment: thanks @CaseyCrookston, did you try what i proposed?

Comment: If it is a new column you are adding via migration maybe you can also do this:'AddColumn("dbo.Revisions", "IsReleased", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true));`, but I remembered it doesn't work properly one time that I tried

Comment: Yes, that's what I've got.  I think this (your) answer is going to be THE answer. Can  you change it to reflect the comment you just made?

Comment: Ok, this nailed it.  Modifying the configuration class was the key.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use this to take care of existing and future c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "0")

Answer (score 44):

You can avoid using fields and take advantage of [Auto-property initialization](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2015/03/19/c.net-little-wonders-auto-property-initialization-in-c-6.aspx), a feature new in C# 6.

This will set the default value to `true` when the column is added to your database.

```
public class Revision
{
    ...
    public Boolean IsReleased { get; set; } = true;
    ....
}
```

Edit to include [@BrewMate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5166245/brewmate)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936566/how-to-set-a-default-value-on-a-boolean-in-a-code-first-model/40937183#comment69089316_40937183):

> If all of your values set to false when you update the database, make sure to have the JSON formatter handle default values. The JSON formatter will ignore default values by default and then your database is setting the boolean to its default value, `false`. See the link below, I would try Default as the enumeration: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm

Comment: ah ok!  Will this set existing rows in existing DB's to true when the column is added?

Comment: Yes. I've used this same technique when adding new columns to my database.

Comment: I had to rescind this as the answer.  It set all the values to False when I did a database-update

Comment: @Casey Crookston You did well to update your question because judging from other answers a lot of people here, including me, got confused about what actually are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston The reason all your values set to false when you updated the database is because you need to have the json formatter handle default values. The json formatter will ignore default values by default and then your database is setting the boolean to it's default value, false. See the link below, I would try Default as the enumeration. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm

Comment: @Alex... it was right there in plain English, but, I took your advice.

Comment: I test Auto-property initialization but it not worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

> According to the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), DefaultValueAttribute specifies the default value for a property. You can use DefaultValueAttribute as the
>   following:

```
public class Revision
{
    ...
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public Boolean IsReleased { get; set; } = true;
    ....
}
```

Furthermore you can use UP() method inside of DbMigration class as the following:

```
public partial class InitializeDb : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
            CreateTable(
            "dbo.Revision",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ...
                    IsReleased = c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true),
                    ...
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
    }
}
```

You should add "defaultValue: true" by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I wasn't on the version of C# to be able to use @Brandon Minnick's suggestion which seems the simplest. Other suggestions just seemed like to much work instead I ended up doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46436861/1819403

Answer (score -1):

You can simply avoid auto-implemented properties and set the property value to `true` when you initialize your object.

```
private Boolean _isReleased = true;
public Boolean IsReleased 
{ 
    get
    {
        return _isReleased;
    }
    set
    {
        _isReleased = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I was hoping it would be this simple.  Will this set existing rows in existing DB's to true when the column is added?

Comment: No. To do that you simply make sure you set default value of your column to `TRUE` when you create it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187872.aspx

Comment: Ok, but the idea here is that we are doing this via Entity Framework code-first migrations.  That's the whole point.