# Set Default value to column Code-First approach

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have created bool field in Database model

Here is it
`public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }`

I need to set default value 'false' to column

So every new entry will have false value in this column

How I can make this via codefirst in migrations?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take advantage of using auto-property initialization:

```
public virtual bool IsActive {get; set} = false;
```

For more info suggest you to check this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40937124/9709828

Comment: Nope. This is not good way. Because this is DB field and it better to use it in migrations