# Entity framework 6.1.3 set default value

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have the following class.

```
public class User 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

}
```

How can I set default value for property `IsDeleted` using Fluent API. Method `HasDefaultValue` is not available. I have tried to set via constructor, the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using C#6 +, it has added [the ability to assign a default value to auto-properties](https://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2014/11/csharp-6-auto-property.html). So you can simply write something like this:

```
public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
```

This will set the default value to false when this column is added to your database.

Comment: The same result. I use automatic migration. Could it be the reason?

Comment: @maciejka What does the *The same result* is? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Are you using Automapper?

Comment: No, I don't use.

Comment: @S.Akbari, When I make automatic migration the columns has been created in the same way like before, when property didn;t have expression with false.

Comment: Given the comments under the question were deleted: this code assigns a default value _to the POCO_, while the default value of a `bool` already is `false`. The OP is asking how to configure a database column to have a default value, allowing you to omit that column in an INSERT clause. That's an entirely different thing from assigning default values to POCO properties. Configuring Entity Framework Migrations to assign a default value to a database column is explained in [Entity Framework 6 Code first Default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554050/).

Comment: @CodeCaster The OP has accepted the answer finally. I think you may want to change your mind about this answer and your downvote!

Comment: Nope, I still stand by my last comment.

Comment: Can confirm, migration created without default value

Comment: This answer is misleading, setting the default value on the auto properties does not affect the values passed as the `DEFAULT` if testing the migration script from `update-database`.