# Enity Framework - Change default value

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have have a SQL Server table with default values on a lot of columns. An example is `ModifiedDtm` (the time where the row was last modified), which will have `GETDATE()` as default value. To avoid clashing with this, I have implemented it the following way in Entity Framework 6.2, using a code first approach:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public DateTime ModifiedDtm { get; set; }
```

This makes the default value works as intended when the row is created. However, it prevents me from ever updating the column again.

How do I make it so that SQL default values can be used, but still allow changing the value with EF later on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 6 Code first Default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554050/entity-framework-6-code-first-default-value)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using fluent API for this. In your context class add small bit for setting default value like below using [HasDefaultValueSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions.hasdefaultvaluesql?view=efcore-2.1)

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<YourEntity> YourEntities{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
            .Property(b => b.Created)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
    }
}
```

**NOTE: This solution requires EF Core**

Comment: I don't see any option called `.HasDefaultValueSql()` for the `.Property()` method. Do I have to include something, somewhere?

Comment: This odesn't answer the question because `HasDefaultValueSql` is available in EF Core not in EF 6.

Comment: @Noceo you can check the duplicated link and know how to configure that with EF 6.

Comment: @CodeNotFound thanks, I am trying to figure out how to use that answer :-)