# How to insert a default value in sql table column in code

Tags: c#, sql, code-first

I want to insert in a column a value like `Eastern Time Zone` but I didn't get any value in the column. In the code below I try, unsuccessfully, to insert a default value:

```
 [MaxLength(150), DefaultValue("Eastern Time Zone")]
 public string Timezone { get; set; }
```

Could you please help me to insert a default value?

Comment: Can you please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554050/entity-framework-6-code-first-default-value/27920032

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following from the fluent API: 
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasdefaultvaluesql-method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
        .Property(b => b.Timezone)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("Eastern Time Zone");
}
```